# Covering by open sets of a normal compact turning into covering by compacts.

Tags: general-topology, compactness

In Algebraic Topology, Allen Hatcher, at Proposition A.16 he uses this:

> Let $K$ be a (Hausdorff hence) normal compact and $U_i$ a finite family of open sets that covers K, then you can find compacts $K_i\subset U_i$ covering K.

I cannot see why this is true.

Comment: I am unable to find that statement in Hatcher's textbook (I mean, at the proof of Proposition A.16). It is an interesting problem, though.

Comment: It is used at the lats paragraph when he covers $K$ by $f^{-1}(U_i)$ etc. The proposition is the one that says (in case I have another numbering):

The map $X^{Y\times Z}\rightarrow (X^Y)^Z$, $f\mapsto \hat{f}$, is a homeomorphism if $Y$ is locally compact Hausdorff and $Z$ is Hausdorff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick $U_i$ and any $x\in U_i$. Since $K$ is normal then $\{x\}$ and $K\backslash U_i$ can be separated by open neighbourhoods. Let $V_x$ be such a neighbourhood of $x$. It follows that $\overline{V_x}\subseteq U_i$ and obviously $\overline{V_x}$ is compact. Also since $x\in V_x$ then $V_x$ is an open cover of $K$. Normally we would end here but we want to refine this family so that indexes agree, i.e. $K_i\subseteq U_i$. With $V_x$ it doesn't match (i.e. there may be multiple distinct $V_x\subseteq U_i$).

Since $K$ is compact then $V_x$ has a finite subcover of $K$. Now for this subcover define

$$W_i:=\bigcup\big\{V_x\ \big|\ \overline{V_x}\subseteq U_i\big\}$$

Note that

$$\overline{W_i}=\bigcup\big\{\overline{V_x}\ \big|\ \overline{V_x}\subseteq U_i\big\}$$

because the family on the right is finite. It follows that $W_i$ is open, $\overline{W_i}\subseteq U_i$ (obviously compact) and $W_i$ (hence $\overline{W_i}$) covers $K$.

Comment: So it is no so difficult to prove it using that is Hausdorff regular, normality was not the right (or at least not totally trivial) thing to think of. Thank you!