# A sub-covering consisted of compact sets which are subsets of the original open covering

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Let $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ be a compact set with an open finite covering $(O_i)_{i=1,...,n}$. Then there exist compact sets $K_i \subset O_i$, $\forall i =1,...,n$ such that $K \subset \bigcup^n_{i=1} K_i$.

I came across this line of reasoning in a proof of partition of unity. However, I could not find the proof. In fact, I could prove this for open balls, not open sets.

Any hint would be highly appreciated :D. Thank you!

Comment: Indeed, I just fixed it. Wrong click on drop-down list.

Comment: Providing more concrete context (e.g., few lines of the proof where the above is used) might help us understand exactly where and how the above claim was used in the proof.

Comment: There is in fact no more context. This is the first line of the proof of partition of unity by the author Gerrit van Dijk on his book Distribution Theory, De Gruyter, page 7, Lemma 2.5. Using the above setting with $K$ and the covering, the lemma says there exists a partition of unity blah blah... and the author starts the proof by saying "select compacts $K_i \subset O_i$ s.t $K \subset \cup K_i$", nothing more.

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2445884/833796. Essentially, cover $K$ by open sets whose closure is compact and contained in some $O_i$, obtain a finite subcover and group the sets so that we have the required containment.

Comment: @redwhisker, can you briefly explain why in that proof $\bar V(x) \subset U_i$?

Comment: Oh, I found out, never mind then...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof linked in the comment requires the fact that compact $K \subset \mathbb R^n$ is normal. Here is a direct proof in $\mathbb R^n$.

We can assume that $O_i$'s are bounded (if not, take the intersection with the open set $\{ x \in \mathbb R^n: d(x,K) < r \}$, for some $r>0$) and denote their boundaries as $\partial O_i$'s. Let

$$ U^\epsilon_i := O_i \cap \{x \in R^n: d(x,\partial O_i) > \epsilon  \}, \quad i =1,...,n. $$

$U^\epsilon_i$'s are open as each of them is an intersection of two open sets. Clearly for any $x\in K$, there exists $i \in \{ 1,...,n\}$ and $\epsilon>0$ such that $x \in U^\epsilon_i$. Therefore, the collection $\{U_i^\epsilon, i = 1,...,n, \epsilon >0 \}$ forms an open covering of $K$.

It will suffice if we can show

$$ \bar U^\epsilon_i :=  O_i \cap \{x \in R^n: d(x,\partial O_i) \geq \epsilon  \}, \quad i =1,...n $$

is closed, hence compact (as $O_i$'s are bounded), because $U^\epsilon_i \subset \bar U^\epsilon_i \subset O_i$. This is not too hard, let $(x_n) \subset \bar U^\epsilon_i$ converging to $x$, by the continuity of $y \mapsto d(y, \partial O_i)$, it holds $d(x,\partial O_i) \geq \epsilon$ and clearly $x \in \bar O_i$ so $x\in O_i$, thus $x \in U^\epsilon_i$.

Finally, do some basic grouping job just like in the link at the end. The grouping of finite cover $(\bar U^\epsilon_i)$ will satisfy your need.